# Close program when the user presses Alt+X

Tags: vb.net

I have an assignment from school where the program is supposed to close when the user presses <kbd>Alt  X</kbd>.

I have done this using Java but that was a long time ago and I can't remember how I did it. How do you do it in VB?

Thanks for the help

Edit:
Thank you for all the help.

But i cant get it to work:

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Alt AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.X Then
    Application.Exit()
End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this (and for a form, make sure `KeyPreview=True`):

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
  If e.Alt AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.X Then
    Application.Exit()
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. but the user has to press alt before x

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the following events, one them should suit your needds. You then should be able to alter the examples given in the MSDN pages to do what you want -

- KeyDown -
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx
- KeyPress -
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx
- KeyUp -
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup.aspx

Answer (score 1):

you want some thing like this.
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/100504-key-pressed-event/

Answer (score 1):

You have keydown, keyup and some other events you can use to check what keys is being pressed

Answer (score 1):

[LarsTech's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111033/close-program-when-the-user-presses-altx/8111875#8111875) is more versatile, but there is this quick method.

Put a button on the form with `Text = "E&xit"`.  This will underline the `x` in `Exit` and make it work with the Alt+X key combo.  Then you can add code to the `ExitButton.Click` event to exit the application.  This has the added benefit of providing a clickable button as an alternate method of closing the application.