# Key Press to Close Form VB.net

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms-designer

So I've been working on this project to autorun on my flash drive, whenever it gets plugged it. It just displays my contact info and a little message, so I can get it returned.

Because I want people to actually read the message, the close button is disabled. You have to check a little box, and then hit the "OK" button.

Of course, I don't want to do this whenever I plug in my own flash drive. I'm trying to make a keyboard shortcut to close it automatically. I saw this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111033/close-program-when-the-user-presses-altx) but it didn't work for me. Here's the code from that post:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If e.Alt AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.X Then
Application.Exit()
End If
End Sub
```

Any help is very appreciated. Thanks!

Also, if you think my code is sloppy and want to clean it up, here it is.

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    e.Cancel = True
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonOK.Click
    End
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        ButtonOK.Enabled = True
    Else
        ButtonOK.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If e.Alt AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.X Then
        End
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You don't need an `If...Else` in your `CheckedChanged` event handler. If you look at the code you can see that you are effectively setting the `Enabled` property of the `Button` to the same value as the `Checked` property of the `CheckBox`, so that's what you should actually do: `ButtonOK.Enabled = CheckBox1.Checked`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Ah, good to know as well. Probably going to rewrite all the code anyway, pretty horrible right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, **NEVER EVER** use `End`. That is just plain bad under any circumstances.

What you should be doing is testing the `Checked` value of your `CheckBox` in the `FormClosing` event handler and cancelling if and only if it's not checked. Logically, you should then check the `CheckBox` and call `Close` on the form when you detect that desired key combination.

Actually, I'd probably not call `Close` either, but rather call `PerformClick` on the `Button`.  That way, the key combination is guaranteed to do exactly the same thing as clicking the `Button`.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonOK.Click
    Close()
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    ButtonOK.Enabled = CheckBox1.Checked
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If e.Alt AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.X Then
        CheckBox1.Checked = True
        ButtonOK.PerformClick()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    e.Cancel = Not CheckBox1.Checked
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'll go try that, but I'm pretty new to coding so I might mess it up. Learning experiences are good though :)

Comment: Ok, I don't know if we're thinking of the same thing, or I'm just stumped.

I want to close the program using the shortcut, without checking the box. Everyone else has to check the box, and then click OK

Comment: What you want is to avoid having to check the box manually. I'm talking about checking the box in code. See the code example I have provided.

Comment: Ah, I see! Lemme go test that out real quick, and see how it works. Thanks so much for all the help!

Comment: The keyboard shortcut still doesn't work. Weird... what you did totally makes sense.

Comment: I tested that exact code and it worked for me. You need to have the form's `KeyPreview` property set to `True` for it to raise keyboard events when other controls that can receive keyboard input have focus. Maybe that's your issue.

Comment: Yup, that was the problem all along. I saw people saying that, but I thought that just made it so you see the letters you type in a textbox, apposed to asterisk for a password.

Well, thanks for cleaning up my code and all the problem solving work!

Comment: Don't assume things like that, especially when people are telling you otherwise. Always read the relevant documentation. There's a Help menu there for a reason. The documentation for the `KeyPreview` property would have told you what it's for.